# запуск файла с параметрами

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-os

Нужно запустить одновременно несколько файлов приложения с cmd параметрами. Получилось так:

```
subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files\\xxx.exe', 'D:\\xxx.mp4', '/параметры'])
```

Параметры модуля subprocess работают частично.. например "/open" (и подобные однословные) - работают, а на "/volume 50" пишет:

> В командной строке найдены неопознанные переключатели.

С модулем os работают все параметры.

Comment: Ну так может имя и значение параметра нужно разделять друг от друга? `'/volume', '50'`

Comment: Попробуйте наоборот слепить параметры `'"/volume 50"'`

Comment: @andreymal все гениальное просто. спасибо )